# Send Proxy GET/POST to WebBrowser

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, indy, indy10

I am trying to intercept GET/POST that i get from IdHTTPProxyServer and send it to IdHTTP so i can replicate the GET/POST and eventually get cookies so I can login in to any website.

How can this be improved? If i try to execute this code it crashes.

```
procedure TForm1.IdHTTPProxyServer1HTTPDocument(
  AContext: TIdHTTPProxyServerContext; var VStream: TStream);
begin

if AContext.Command='POST' then begin
EmbeddedWB1.LoadFromString(IdHTTP1.Post(AContext.Target,AContext.Headers.Text)); << CRASH
end;

if AContext.Command='GET' then begin
EmbeddedWB1.LoadFromString(IdHTTP1.Get(AContext.Target)); << CRASH
end;

end;
```

Comment: What crashes exactly?  You need to be more specific.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Everytime i try to connect to a website with IE it crashes with EmbeddedWB when it tries to load the html to EmbeddedWB.
The html returned from IdHttp is there however the EmbeddedWB fails to load it. :(

Comment: Well, `TEmbeddedWB` is a visual UI component, and `TIdHTTPProxyServer` is a multi-threaded component, so that might have something to do with it.  You can't access UI components from the context of a worker thread, only the context of the main UI thread.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Long live the Chromium Embedded Console Browser :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `OnHTTPDocument` event, you need to look at the `TIdHTTPProxyServerContext.TransferSource` property to know if the event is being triggered for a client request that contains body data, or is being triggered for the target server's response to the client request.  Sending your own `GET`/`POST` request only makes sense when processing client requests, however the `OnHTTPDocument` event is not likely to ever be triggered for a `GET` request since there is no body data to capture.

You don't need to use `TIdHTTP` in order to get the server's cookies.  Let `TIdHTTPProxyServer` do its work normally, and then you can extract the cookies from the `TIdHTTPProxyServerContext.Headers` property in the `OnHTTPResponse` event, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.IdHTTPProxyServer1HTTPResponse(AContext: TIdHTTPProxyServerContext);
var
  Cookies: TStringList;
begin
  Cookies := TStringList.Create;
  try
    AContext.Headers.Extract('Set-Cookie', Cookies);
    // use Cookies as needed, such as:
    // URI := TIdURI.Create(AContext.Target);
    // try
    //   CookieManager1.AddServerCookies(Cookies, URI);
    // finally
    //   URI.Free;
    // end;
  finally
    Cookies.Free;
  end;
end;
```